# Discord Node JS TypeError: args.slice is not a function

Tags: args

I am trying to code my discord js bot and I am updating my command handler and with my hastebin command I use args and it says args.slice is not a function yet it has worked before hand. Here is my current code:

```
    module.exports = {
        config: {
            name: `hastebin`,
            description: 'Sends pinging... => pong latency',
            usage: "hastbin <extension (js, ts, ...)> <code>",
            aliases: [`hastebin`, `hastebingen`],
        },
        run: async (message, args) => {
    const extension = args[0];
    const code = args.slice(1).join(" ");

    if (!args.length) {
      return message.channel.send(
        "Please write your text or code to generate hastebin link"
      );
    }
    if(message && message.deletable) message.delete().catch(e => {});
    try {
      const haste = await hastebin(`${code}`, { extension: `${extension}` });

      message.channel.send(haste);
    } catch (e) {
      return message.channel.send(
        "Something went wrong, Please try again later."
      );
    }
  },
};
```

If anyone has a fix please comment :)))

Answer (score 0):

The `slice` statement used above needs a starting index and an ending index. And the variable `args` is an array (or so I believe) so you can't have a `join` statement on a `slice`d array because the `slice` statement gives you an array as a result whereas the `join` statement is for strings. So, if you're trying to add an element to the end of the array then use the `push()` statement.